# Is there a way to exclude a folder from a TerraformAsset?

Tags: terraform, terraform-cdk

I am following this guide for getting a docker image to run on AWS ECS:

https://github.com/cdktf/docker-on-aws-ecs-with-terraform-cdk-using-typescript/tree/main

In their 'build and push' docker step they do this:

```js
    const asset = new TerraformAsset(this, `project`, {
      path: projectPath,
    });

    const version = require(`${projectPath}/package.json`).version;
    this.tag = `${repo.repositoryUrl}:${version}-${asset.assetHash}`;
    // Workaround due to https://github.com/kreuzwerker/terraform-provider-docker/issues/189
    this.image = new Resource(this, `image`, {
      provisioners: [
        {
          type: "local-exec",
          workingDir: asset.path,
          command: `docker login -u ${auth.userName} -p ${auth.password} ${auth.proxyEndpoint} && 
  docker build -t ${this.tag} . && 
  docker push ${this.tag}`,
        },
      ],
    });
```

That is - they use a hash of the directory that makes up the Dockerfile as the tag for the Docker file.

This means that the docker image will not need to be rebuilt if nothing has changed.

The problem I have is my folder structure looks like this:

```
/
  backend/
  frontend/
  infra/
     cdktf.json
     main.ts 
  Dockerfile
```

Note the Dockerfile is in the root directory.

During the cdktf synth process cdktf will copy the entire directory, including `cdktf.out` itself, into the `infra/cdktf.out` folder and recursively keep copying until it hits an ENAMETOOLONG error.

A good solution for me would be to either be able to specify specific files/directories for the TerraformAsset, or exclude certain folders from it.

This github issue:

https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-cdk/issues/2113

Proposes adding functionality to ignore folders. I'm wondering if there is an immediate solution.

Adding a `.terraformignore` does not solve this problem.